# In Rest Assured, getString() round off the decimal values after 4 digit

Tags: java, rest-assured-jsonpath

I have scenario, we need to read the latitude and Longitude from json response body.
The latitude and longitude has value like below

```
"data": [{
  "city": "Mumbai",
  "country": "India",  
  "latitude": 19.0886993408,
  "longitude": 72.8678970337
  
}
```

when We try to validate the JSON response by reading the latitude and longitude using JSONPATH
using `getString()` then it round off the value after 4 digit in decimal places.

Below is the code in java

```
String key = item.getKey();
String value = item.getValue();
JsonPath jsonPathEvaluator = response.jsonPath();
String strjson = jsonPathEvaluator.getString(key).toString().replaceAll("\\[\\](){}]", "");
```

Output display:

Latitude:-19.0887 instead of 19.0886993408

Comment: could you please try `String.format("%.4f %%", value);`

Comment: value is already coming from excel, here using the "key" we are reading the json response body. key=data.latitude, which is passed into getString but getString only return 19.0887

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with JsonPath.config as mentioned [**here**](https://www.codota.com/code/java/classes/io.restassured.path.json.config.JsonPathConfig)

Using it you can provide your custom configuration for JsonPath.
Here i am just trying to convert my numeric data with long decimal range double.

```
String key = item.getKey();
String value = item.getValue();
JsonPath jsonPathEvaluator = response.jsonPath();
JsonPath.config = new JsonPathConfig(JsonPathConfig.NumberReturnType.DOUBLE);
String strjson = jsonPathEvaluator.getString(key).toString().replaceAll("\\[\\](){}]", "");


/* String json = "{\n" +
"  \"data\": {\n" +
"    \"city\": \"Mumbai\",\n" +
"    \"country\": \"India\",\n" +
"    \"latitude\": 19.0886993408,\n" +
"    \"longitude\": 72.8678970337\n" +
"  }\n" +
"}";
JsonPath jsonPath = JsonPath.from(json);
JsonPath.config = new JsonPathConfig(JsonPathConfig.NumberReturnType.DOUBLE);
double strjson = jsonPath.get("data.latitude");
    
System.out.println(String.valueOf(strjson)); */
```

For me it's printing below output.

**`19.0886993408`**

Comment: Hi, we are reading the input from excel where data.latitude=19.0886993408 store as expected. So we read key =data.latitude. key=data.city which we pass into code line as "String strjson = jsonPathEvaluator.getString(key).toString().replaceAll("\\[\\](){}]", ""); ", in this data.city is coming properly but data.latutude is round off . we cannot use the above code only for latitude, we are developing framework. Please suggest some common functions

Comment: Just try to add this line before `JsonPath.config = new JsonPathConfig(JsonPathConfig.NumberReturnType.DOUBLE);` before last line.

Comment: @VipinSingh , You can try updated answer. It will work.

Comment: here instead of double strjson = jsonPath.get("data.latitude"); . I am using this as double strjson = jsonPath.get(key); its giving me error

Comment: can you modify the above code , String json, from where r u picking this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219953/discussion-between-sagar-gangwal-and-vipin-singh).

Comment: String key = item.getKey();
String value = item.getValue();
JsonPath jsonPathEvaluator = response.jsonPath();
JsonPath.config = new JsonPathConfig(JsonPathConfig.NumberReturnType.DOUBLE);
String strjson = jsonPathEvaluator.getString(key).toString().replaceAll("\\[\\](){}]", "");

Comment: I need help , Can u please help me>

Comment: @VipinSingh Sure Vipin.